# require_once not working on MacBook Pro ( Mountain Lion ) but working on all other platforms

Tags: php, macos, apache

I've got a strange problem, i tried both MAMP and the standard install of PhP / Apache on my MacBook Pro and always get this error

> Warning:
>   require_once(../interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar-premium/app/strategies/get_data_from_cache/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-db-cache.php
>   on line 3 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '../interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear')
>   in
>   /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar-premium/app/strategies/get_data_from_cache/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-db-cache.php
>   on line 3

from this call

```
require_once ( '/../interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php' );
```

I'm new to Mac and so it must be something really stupid, but i'm blocked.

Of course i tried every version

```
require_once ( '../interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php' );

require_once ( './../interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php' );
```

Comment: I know this is going to sound stupid, but, the files you're trying to require exist at the path you're trying to require them right?

Comment: @sabre yes of cours, on windows everything works fine

Comment: well that's one potential issue ruled out ;). Another possibility could be that your include_path isn't set correctly?

Comment: @sabre my idea was simply to tell: "go up one directory and then get interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php", maybe it's an issue with include,  rigth now my include path is (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear')

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense:

```
require_once ( '/../interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php' );
```

You are starting at root directory and then trying to go up a directory from there.

Try to type in your actual full file path and see if that works.

Comment: i just mean go back one directory. On windows it works. on Mac i can't seem to be able to say "go back one directory"

Comment: if i hardcode require_once (  '/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar-premium/app/strategies/interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php' ); everything works

Comment: So what directory is the code that is executing this script in?

Comment: The error is Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear') in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar-premium/app/strategies/get_data_from_cache/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-db-cache.php on line 3

Comment: maybe it's something related to permissions

Comment: I wouldn't think it is permissions if it works with full path specified. Do you have a symbolic link in there somewhere, as they can cause problems with using includes/requires with relative paths?

Comment: no symbolic link. i heard someone mention the fact that there are security restriction which do not allow you to go up one directory, because if i copy the files so that interfaces is a child of my directory and then call require_once ( 'interfaces/class-ai1ec-get-data-from-cache.php' ); everything works as expected

Comment: Maybe a directory permission issue (i.e. your apache user does not have permission on strategies directory to be able to select it)?